# What data contained in this message, specifically, is used to verify the signature in this message assuming I have the correct public key?

Tags: sha256

I'm trying to validate this message using a public key that I know is good. If I had the code in php or c++, that would be perfect. Ideally, I just need to know the data that is being used from the message.

Below is the sample message.

```
 -----BEGIN TR34_Sample_CA_KRD.p7b-----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-----END TR34_Sample_CA_KRD.p7b-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. Basically, it's the sequence tag and all the data under the sequence tag that's at the same level as the sequence tag containing the signature. Do not include the tags or data above it. Do not include the signature or the sequence tag of the signature.

[ASN.1 DECODED DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPUHh.png)